# Maven: how can I deploy two artifacts with the release plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

My project generates two jar: the `original-artifact-name.jar` and the `artifact-name.jar` (I have shade plugin setup). 
I want to use `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` and be able to deploy not only the simple jar but also the origial one.

So far I am invoking the mave deploy:file goal manually after the release plugin has been executed. How can I incorporate this step in the release plugin execution?

Edit: this is my attempt with `maven-deploy-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy-nodeps</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy-file</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <configuration>
          <file>${basedir}/target/original-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <classifier>nodeps</classifier>
          <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
          <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagement.repository.id}</repositoryId>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

which for some reasons is deploying the main jar in the snapshot repo, while the nodeps jar in the release repo. This is my repositories setup

```
<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>maven-snapshots</id>
  <url>https://repo.com/maven-snapshots</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>maven-releases</id>
  <url>https://repo.com/maven-releases</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Remove the configuration for maven-deploy-plugin and just use `mvn clean deploy` see if this works...otherwise please post your full pom file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy additional files, you can configure the `deploy:deploy-file` goal in the POM.

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>deploy-bo</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
         </goals>
         <phase>deploy</phase>
         <configuration>
            <file>${basedir}/target/bo.jar</file>
            <pomFile>${basedir}/target/somewhere/pom-bo.xml</pomFile>
            <url>${project.distributionManagementArtifactRepository.url}</url>
            <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagementArtifactRepository.id}</repositoryId>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: does this deploy the second artifact in the release automatically? how can I check what the release step will deploy without actually doing it? (I tried the `-DdryRun=true` but I am not able to see what it is going to be deployed)

Comment: It adds the goal to the `deploy` phase. The `deploy` phase is called when you `release:perform`. For testing purposes, you can call `mvn deploy` which will build and deploy the Snapshot version.

Comment: the deploy plugin cannot find the jar. Does the deploy plugin invoke the package?

Comment: Calling `deploy` also invokes all previous steps, including `package`. I guess you misspelled the artifact or the path.

Comment: it tries to deploy to the `release` repo, am I missing some important parameter here? (for some reasons the artifact name is not ending with -SNAPSHOT)

Comment: When you call `package`, the artifact in `target` does not have a snapshot version?

Comment: it does, both of them have SNAPSHOT

Comment: I guess you need to write a new question with your configuration and the error description because without your pom, I guess we cannot go further.

Comment: I added the relevant pom section

Comment: I think I found the problem. Opening a new question to address it. Thanks

Comment: What is pomFile tag for ?